# Place Shopify products on external landing page

Tags: shopify

Is there any way API or plug-in that would allow me to pull products from the Shopify store and place them on an external landing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the shopify Admin API
Reference - https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: Thank you, is there any plug-in that you know of and could get integrated with WordPress to display those products?

Comment: This looks promising. I've never used it though. https://github.com/namwen/Shopify-Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Shopify has very useful built-in product called the Buy Button where you can place product(s) for sale on external pages like WP and you get your sales integrated nicely to your Shopify checkout.

That is your best bet. The Admin API is not really appropriate for your use case, although you could make some hack jobs that could work.